# In Excel search for 2 text strings in column and return result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have looked everywhere for an answer to this but can't find exactly what I'm looking for.  I have a list of SKU's and Colours and then a list of filenames which contain the SKU and the colour, what I would like is to search the column of filenames for the image that ties up with the sku and colour and return the result.  See below:

SKU:  1055, 1099, 1066
Colour: Black, Red, Grey
Filename: 1055_Deluxe_T_Shirt_black.jpg,1099_Deluxe_T_Shirt_grey.jpg  etc

In this example the SKU of 1055 with a colour of black would be attributed to 1055_Deluxe_T_Shirt_black.jpg

The list of filenames are in a random order and I need to search the filenames to look for both the sku and colour text string, once found rather than a yes/no response I need the filename to populate the cell. This is assuming sku, colour and filenames are all in the same spreadsheet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$3,MATCH(1,IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(A2),$H$2:$H$3)))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(B2),$H$2:$H$3))),1,0),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Also limit the List range to the maximum extants.  Array formulas calculations are exponential, so avoid full column references.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your answer, I've tried replicating this with my fields with no such luck.  Is there any chance you can upload your example file for download please so I can work off that?

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter after changing the formula to match your list range?  If you did it correctly Excel will automatically put the `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Yes I did,  I've copied your spreadsheet exactly and for the top line I get the wrong filename attributed to the 1055 black.  Not sure why this is as all I changed was the range in which it searched, so I changed $H$3 to $H$100.  Also how do you replicate this down column C as I get N/A for all rows.

Comment: Post the formula as you have it now.

Comment: =INDEX($H$2:$H$100,MATCH(1,IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,$H$2:$H$100)))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B3,$H$2:$H$100))),1,0),0))

Comment: is this in C2 or C3?

Comment: Hi Scott,  Been trying to sort this all night, thanks for the file its a huge help.  I got your formula working great for one row but copying it down didn't seem to work.  Could you take a look and see where I've gone wrong https://www.dropbox.com/s/kyawav7udf8hvqt/garbage.xlsx?dl=0.  I had it working at one point but it didn't pick up all the fields in A&B and returned N/A for filenames that were there.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple but I just can't see it.

Comment: You have a space in front of all the colors.  So instead of "Black" it is searching for " Black" which does not exist. To fix this either fix every cell or use `Trim(B2)` instead of `B2`.  See edit.

Comment: Scott you are an absolute superstar.  I just didn't see that, thank you so much.  All working now.